# Json Post method return null values in C#

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

> Can i send the data from webisite to Database Via  Wcf Post Method
>   service call.The data saved to databse but i unable to receive the
>   message. It returns null value.

```
        byte[] data;
        Stream stream ;
        DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));
        LoginDetails student = new LoginDetails { Name = "Mohanraj", LoginType = 1,Password="qssaz",Mobile="86945",imei="asdfdasasaa",LoginID="ab@b.com" }; 
        WebClient Proxy1 = new WebClient();
        Proxy1.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializerToUplaod = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(LoginDetails));
        serializerToUplaod.WriteObject(ms, student);
        data = Proxy1.UploadData("http://songapp.ccpvl.com/Services/BasicService.svc/MemberRegistration", "POST", ms.ToArray());
        stream = new MemoryStream(data);
        obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(LoginDetails));
        var resultStudent = obj.ReadObject(stream) as LoginDetails;
        Console.WriteLine(resultStudent.LoginID+" " + resultStudent.Name);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: If you're going to post a question consisting entirely of a piece of code, please at least make the code readable.

Answer (score 0):

In this code working.......................

```
        try
        {

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Services/BasicService.svc/MemberRegistration");

            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                var NAME= "adss";
                var LoginTypes = 1;
                var Passwords = "asasaytsasasa"; var MobileNo = "23456fd587"; var imeino = "e35tfgg5"; var LoginIDs = "abfcsdskghj@google.com";

                string jSonData = "{" + "\"Name\":\"" + NAME + "\"," + "\"LoginType\":\"" + LoginTypes + "\"," + "\"Password\":\"" + Passwords + "\"," + "\"Mobile\":\"" + MobileNo + "\"," + "\"imei\":\"" + imeino + "\"," + "\"LoginID\":\"" + LoginIDs + "\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(jSonData);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }


        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Comment: You know empty catch block means any exception thrown will disappear right?